# How to know when a post is only useful to the OP?

Tags: discussion, flags, close-reasons

I recently saw a post that longer exists because the OP deleted it per someone's request.

The OP had a question about a JavaScript error that returned undefined for an index. I have seen these types of questions in the past here on SO.

In the case of the post that was deleted by the OP, the comment was that it was only useful to them and nobody else and so it was flagged to be closed.

The user realized that they were trying to iterate through some questions in a `json` object using a keyword that was undefined. If I recall correctly the OP used `q.options[0]` instead of `q.answers[0]`. The `answers` being defined, `options` not being defined anywhere.

In what way was this not useful to another user who may run into the same problem in the future?

Comment: From what you are describing.. it appears like a simple typographical error. These are general solved when you take a break or a fresh cup of coffee. Searching through Stackoverflow will not help in such cases

Comment: It's a very generic problem that falls in the category of making a typo. There is no clear cut solution to an undefined keyword other than "debug your code better".

Comment: hmm, I see your point.

Comment: This is either a "typo question" (which is hard to find if someone has a similar typo (which itself is rare)) or a duplicate anyway, so I don't think this particular question is worth to keep (I haven't seen the original question).

Comment: Okay, so a typo type of post would be closed and what reasons would I use to close it? So, like off-topic, but then?

Comment: retagged as discussion.. not a bug in SO

Comment: @SurajRao, if you want to post as answer. Thank you all. Something to add to my toolbox when reviewing posts.

Comment: Flag -> should be closed... -> off-topic because... -> can no longer be reproduced. That flag type also includes typographical errors

Comment: Ahh, can no longer be reproduced. Thanks @Tom.

Comment: @gnat That dupe target is itself a duplicate. I feel that the ultimate dupe target in this dupe chain, is a better dupe target for this question. More explanation in both question and answer, and closer to this question in spirit.

Comment: How to know? By applying some intelligence and knowledge. We are not expecting a rigorous logical proof.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From what you are describing.. it appears like a simple typographical error. These are general solved when you take a break or a fresh cup of coffee. Searching through StackOverflow will not help in such cases. They tend to be fairly unique to OP's situation.

As for the Close Reason, there is specific one:

> This question was caused by a problem that can no longer be reproduced or a simple typographical error. While similar questions may be on-topic here, this one was resolved in a manner unlikely to help future readers. This can often be avoided by identifying and closely [inspecting the shortest program necessary to reproduce the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before posting.

in the **Off Topic** section. This is for users with close voting privileges. For others it should be in the flags option.

Comment: That said, I wish to state here for the record that asking such questions can be very, very useful to the OP. Mainly of course because you get some new eyeballs to took at your code and spot the bug, but also because things like that can make you realise you do need some AFK time.